# Python trailing comma after print executes next instruction

Tags: python, text

If a trailing comma is added to the end of a print statement, the next statement is executed first. Why is this? For example, this executes `10000 ** 10000` before it prints `"Hi "`:

```
print "Hi",
print 10000 ** 10000
```

And this takes a while before printing "Hi Hello":

```
def sayHello():
    for i in [0] * 100000000: pass
    print "Hello"
print "Hi",
sayHello()
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. In Python 2.x, a trailing `,` in a `print` statement prevents a new line to be emitted.

   - In Python 3.x, use `print("Hi", end="")` to achieve the same effect.
2. The standard output is line-buffered. So the `"Hi"` won't be printed before a new line is emitted.

Comment: Is there an analogue to the trailing comma in python 3? `print('Hi')` doesn't have the same effect.

Answer (score 5):

You're seeing the effects of stdout buffering: [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)

Answer (score 4):

As others mention, standard out is buffered.  You can try using this at points that you need the output to appear:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

print automatically puts a newline at the end of a string. This isn’t necessarily what we want; for example, we might want to print several pieces of data separately and have them all appear on one line. To prevent the newline from being added, put a comma at the end of the print statement:

```
d=6
print d,
print d

Output:
6 6
```