# What's ending comma in print function for?

Tags: python, python-2.x

This code is from http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#predefined-clean-up-actions

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

What I don't understand is what's that `,` for at the end of print command.

I also checked doc, http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print.

Not understanding enough, is it a mistake?(it seems not. it's from the official tutorial).

I am from ruby/javascript and it's unusual for me.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In python 2.7, the comma is to show that the string will be printed on the same line

For example:

```
for i in xrange(10):
     print i,
```

This will print

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

To do this in python 3 you would do this:

```
 for i in xrange(10):
      print(i,end=" ")
```

You will probably find this answer helpful

[Printing horizontally in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458024/cant-figure-out-how-to-print-horizontally-in-python/18458089#18458089)

---- Edit ---

The documentation, http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement, says

> A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma.

Comment: In the python 3 snippet, `xrange` should be replaced with `range`

Answer (score 15):

It prevents the `print` from ending with a newline, allowing you to append a new `print` to the end of the line.

Python 3 changes this completely and the trailing comma is no longer accepted. You use the `end` parameter to change the line ending, setting it to a blank string to get the same effect.

Comment: That seems a wise a movement

Comment: More like a necessary consequence. When ``print`` is a normal function and not a statement, you can't just add random syntax to it.

Comment: This makes much more sense in Python3. The original syntax was really a weird exception out of nowhere that easily confuses people.

Comment: @JIXiang I think it was a feature copied from older languages, I vaguely remember seeing a BASIC that worked that way. I agree the Python 3 way is much better.

Answer (score 5):

From [Python trailing comma after print executes next instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009672/python-trailing-comma-after-print-executes-next-instruction):

1. In Python 2.x, a trailing `,` in a print statement prevents a new line to be emitted.
2. The standard output is line-buffered. So the "Hi" won't be printed before a new line is emitted.

Comment: import sys <snip> sys.stdout.flush() to address the line buffering issue

Comment: or `python -u script.py`

Answer (score 0):

in python 2.7:

```
print line,
```

in python 3.x:

```
print(line, end = ' ')
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site!  Could you please elaborate on this answer?  This shows how to get the same result in Python 2 and Python 3, but it doesn't explain what that result is.