# Trying to solve old GoogleCodeJam for practice

Tags: python

I'm working on some of the old Google Code Jam problems as practice in python since we don't use this language at my school. [Here](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p1) is the current problem I am working on that is supposed to just reverse the order of a string by word.

Here is my code:

```
import sys


f = open("B-small-practice.in", 'r')


T = int(f.readline().strip())


array = []

for i in range(T):
    array.append(f.readline().strip().split(' '))


for ar in array:
    if len(ar) > 1:
        count = len(ar) - 1
        while count > -1:
            print ar[count]
            count -= 1
```

The problem is that instead of printing:

```
test a is this
```

My code prints:

```
test
a
is
this
```

Please let me know how to format my loop so that it prints all in one line. Also, I've had a bit of a learning curve when it comes to reading input from a .txt file and manipulating it, so if you have any advice on different methods to do so for such problems, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: related: [Efficiently reverse the order of the words (not characters) in an array of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47402/4279)

Answer (score 2):

`print` by default appends a newline.  If you don't want that behavior, tack a comma on the end.

```
    while count > -1:
        print ar[count],
        count -= 1
```

Note that a far easier method than yours to reverse a list is just to specify a step of -1 to a slice. (and `join` it into a string)

```
print ' '.join(array[::-1]) #this replaces your entire "for ar in array" loop
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can alter your output format. Here are a few:

---

One way is by [adding a comma at the end of your print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908897/python-whats-ending-comma-in-print-function-for):

```
print ar[count],
```

This makes `print` output a space at the end instead of a newline.

---

Another way is by building up a string, then printing it after the loop:

```
reversed_words = ''
for ar in array:
    if len(ar) > 1:
        count = len(ar) - 1
        while count > -1:
            reversed_words += ar[count] + ' '
            count -= 1
print reversed_words
```

---

A third way is by rethinking your approach, and using some useful built-in Python functions and features to simplify your solution:

```
for ar in array:
    print ' '.join(ar[::-1])
```

(See [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)).

---

Finally, you asked about reading from a file. You're already doing that just fine, but you forgot to [close the file descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) after you were done reading, using `f.close()`. Even better, with Python 2.5+, [you can use the `with` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for):

```
array = list()
with open(filename) as f:
    T = int(f.readline().strip())
    for i in range(T):
        array.append(f.readline().strip().split(' '))

# The rest of your code here
```

This will close the file descriptor `f` automatically after the `with` block, even if something goes wrong while reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
T = int(raw_input())

for t in range(T):
    print "Case #%d:" % (t+1),
    print ' '.join([w for w in raw_input().split(' ')][::-1])
```