# Nested for Loops in Jython, how to include new line to separate outputs?

Tags: excel, newline, jython, nested-loops

Thank you for your help in advance.

I am a Jython beginner and I will gladly appreciate thorough help or explanations.

I have written a couple of lines in such manner...

for a1 in range(1,7):

for a2 in range(1,2):

```
A=a1*a2

print A,
```

for b1 in range(1,7):

for b2 in range(1,2):

```
B=b1*b2*2

print B,
```

The result in the output is such:  1 2 3 4 5 6 2 4 6 8 10 12

I would like to separate the two in such manner:

1 2 3 4 5 6

2 4 6 8 10 12

Using the "\n" command. How is it possible to do? What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A simple print after each loop will do the trick...

```
for a1 in range(1,7):
    for a2 in range(1,2):
        A=a1*a2
        print A, 
print 
for b1 in range(1,7):
    for b2 in range(1,2):
        B=b1*b2*2
        print B,
print
```

Actually printing a "\n" (i.e. print "\n") would also leave a blank line between the two output lines, although I suppose you could do ...

```
print "\n",
```

See also the question [What's ending comma in print function for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908897/whats-ending-comma-in-print-function-for) for more details.