# How to print with whitespace ,or without the \n in python

Tags: loops, printing, whitespace

i have got a task to get a number,letter and print the letter times as the number  with whitespace between them , like a square i mean NxN
for example :[click to see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS3Wi.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you are using Python 2 or 3. This answer provides a solution for your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18908914/830457

Comment: Are you sure? For me this works:
`print("Hello", end=" ")
print(" World", end=" ")`

Comment: You right! my mistake i used the comma instead the end=" "