# Strange behavior of python's print

Tags: python, select, stdin, file-descriptor

```
import select
import sys
inputs=[sys.stdin]
while 1:
    readable,w,e=select.select(inputs,[],inputs)
    for r in readable:
        print 1,
        raw_input()
        print 2
        print 3,
```

when I tried this python code on Ubuntu, suppose I randomly input sth like 'asd' in the terminate. It shows:

```
asd
1 2
asd
3 1 2
```

It seems the behavior of "print blabla," will be influenced by the status of stdin's file descriptor, yet "print blabla" doesn't. Could somebody tell me what is going on there?

Comment: What is `sb`? That's not an English word.

Comment: I mean somebody, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in a comment you are seeing the effects of line buffered standard output in Python 2.x: a trailing `,` in a `print` will prevent it to emit a new line. The text with the trailing `,` will not be printed before a new line is emited. You can remove the buffering with some simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def write(self, msg):
        self.stream.write(msg)

    def flush(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout = Logger(sys.stdout)
    print 'User says hello!',
    print 'Goodbye, cruel world!'
```

As you see `sys.stdout` is replaced with other stream which does a `flush` after every print. You can also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009672/python-trailing-comma-after-print-executes-next-instruction) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between print xxxxxx to print xxxxxx,

```
print "Yes"
```

will print Yes to the screen and add \n (newline)

```
print "Yes",
```

will print print Yes to the screen without \n (newline)

Comment: Thank you. But could you explain why 3 will not present until I make the next input?

Comment: @user2837543 you can check [this question for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009672/python-trailing-comma-after-print-executes-next-instruction)

Comment: @user2837543 can you edit the post output so it will be clear what is input and what is output. you can use >>> for input