# Python console progress

Tags: python, progress

I need to create simple progress in console. Like:

```
Progress: [######] 30% out of 432 combinations
Last 10 tried:
12.12.2013 - this1
12.12.2013 - this2
...
12.12.2013 - this10
```

Pretty simple. I found an ugly way: do clr() each time and do print (for progression).
But I can't understand, how can I print 10 strings down withdifferent data. 10 time print is ugly, data alway changes. Is there a way to some nice log into console? sorry for my english.

My sample code:

```
import os
import time


def cls():
    os.system(['clear', 'cls'][os.name == 'nt'])


def progress(i, l=None):
    total = 400
    a = 100-i*100/total
    cls()
    print "Progress: [%-33s] %d%% out of %d combinations" % ("#"*(a/3), a, total)
    print "Last 10 tried:"
    for j in l:
        print j
    time.sleep(0.3)


i = 400
l = []
while i > 0:
    l.append("%s - %s" % ('11.21.2013', i))
    if len(l) >= 10:
        progress(i, l)
        l = []
    i -= 1
```

That is ehat I need& But I think it can be optimized. Could someone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text Progress Bar in the Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)

Comment: no, i read that thread. It has only 1 line progress. i need 10

Comment: can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I do it as follows

```py
print (current_line * 100 // total_lines, "%", end = '\r')
```

Don't forget, that too many outputs to console will slow down your loops.

Comment: syntax highlight fail. // is integer division operator.

Comment: Didn't know how to do it. So it is special comment.