# Python 2.7.3: Loading animation (custom) while an os.system() command is running

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, os.system

Im making an easy package installer program in a CLI environment with python. and while the part where i execute

```
os.system('dpkg -i ' + packageName + '--yes')
```

i want to add like a loading thing like

```
[####........]
```

while the package installs

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: by my example i assume most people are smart to know what i want and therefore dont need a question to help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console

Comment: by your comment i assume that you are smart to know that people cannot read your mind over the internet and therefore won't answer your "question" to help