# Progress bar using sys.stdout.write not updating

Tags: python, console, progress

I used a code from a previous answer to build a progress bar function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173331/939628

It was working fine until I changed some code ... I have simplified my code to reproduce this issue.

Basically, I'm looping over a number of items and before I'm calculating the number of operations to be done, setting progress to 0, and after each iteration I update the progress to be one more. I also call an update_progress function which should print out the progress %.

It should update the line to the progress but it only shows the print the LAST time you call it (aka when its done at 100%)

What's really odd is that prior to calling update_progress() you call "print" it will work (not quite how its supposed to, which is to update the current line). Even weirder is that I found the bug by removing a function call to a series of functions from another class I wrote .... So somehow that function was "enabling" this printing... EVEN weirder is that the code that "fixed" the issue in the for loop enabled the inital 0% print...

Any idea why the printing is not working?

```
import time
import itertools
import sys

def go():
    items = range(0,10)

    prog = 0.0 #Real so division works
    total = len(items)

    update_progress(0) # Even this intial call doesn't work

    for i in items:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        prog = prog + 1
        # adding print here makes it print the output from below to a new line
        update_progress(int(prog / total * 100))

def update_progress(progress):
    sys.stdout.write('\r[{0}] {1}%'.format('#' * (progress / 10), progress))
```

Comment: Did you try flushing stdout? (Why do you have a carriage return at the start of your format string?)

Comment: I believe the carriage return is so that when a new progress kicks prints, it replaces the last line instead of making a new line. and yes flushing it worked... thanks

Answer (score 2):

`sys.stdout` is buffered, so it isn't guaranteed to display the text immediately. You should flush the buffer after writing your string:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. I'm still utterly confused why the function I was calling fixed it for me before though... Perhaps a few trees down functions there was one of these calls...