# Iterate over large file with progress indicator in Python?

Tags: python

I'm iterating over a large csv file and I'd like to print out some progress indicator. As I understand counting the number of lines would requires parsing all of the file for newline characters. So I cannot easily estimate progress with line number.

Is there anything else I can do to estimate the progress while reading in lines? Maybe I can go by size?

Comment: A few Gigabytes large.

Answer (score 22):

You can use tqdm with large files in the following way:

```
import os
import tqdm

with tqdm.tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(filename)) as pbar:
   with open(filename, "rb") as f:
      for l in f:
          pbar.update(len(l))
          ...
```

If you read a `utf-8` file then your `len(l)` won't give you the exact number of bytes but it should be good enough.

Comment: it has changed to: `with tqdm.tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(file)) as pbar:`

Comment: Maybe better would be to use:
 pbar.update(f.tell() - pbar.n)
instead of:
 pbar.update(len(l))

Comment: @Martin unfortunately, the f.tell() call fails: `OSError: telling position disabled by next() call`

Comment: @fgiraldeau try changing the `for l in f` to `while l := f.readline():`, it should help

Answer (score 8):

You can use `os.path.getsize(filename)` to get the size of your target file. Then as you read data from the file, you can calculate progress percentage using a simple formula
`currentBytesRead/filesize*100%`. This calculation can be done at the end of every N lines.

For the actual progress bar, you take a look at [Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)

Comment: How do I find `currentBytesRead` correctly representing actual bytes, while still reading correct (utf8) characters?

Comment: Only way would be to write a small amount of data to a tempfile in your chosen encoding, and then measure that tempfile size, calculate the character-to-byte ratio. I could be wrong, but this is the only way to ensure it works in a platform independent way, and at all times. This was also the reason, I did not mention it in the answer. It is a topic of its own.

Comment: Not sure, that writing gigabytes of data back would be faster than counting newlines. Maybe the file handle has some position indicator, though?

Comment: Not sure why you thought of writing "gigabytes of data". In my earlier comment  I meant, write a small amount of data(say a single line) to a tempfile, with the required encoding. Then measure the size of the tempfile, to get character-to-bytes ratio. Then, while reading the large file, you can use filehandle.tell() to get a pointer to where you are currently in the file(in terms of number of characters). Then, multiply it with the ratio calculated earlier, to get the currentBytesRead value.

Comment: I thought `f.tell()` would be enough to get a byte position, but I noticed that if you iterate over a file, the `tell()` method is disabled (it reads chunks of 8k, but that's fine with me). I don't think character to bytes is constant enough to estimate for the rest of the file. Another difficulty is that I'm using `csv.reader` which complicates some of the suggestions here. I wish `tell` would work.

Answer (score 6):

Please check this small (and useful) library named **tqdm** https://github.com/noamraph/tqdm
You just wrap an iterator and cool progress meter shows as the loop executes.

The image says it all.

[image]

Comment: It's indeed pretty cool and I will get that. It doesn't quite answer the question, but I like it.

Comment: Is there a way to get the line count with tqdm?

Answer (score 6):

This is based on the @Piotr's answer for Python3

```
import os
import tqdm

with tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(filepath)) as pbar:
    with open(filepath) as file:
        for line in file:
            pbar.update(len(line.encode('utf-8')))
            ....
        file.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use os.path.getsize (or os.stat) to get the size of your text file.
Then whenever you parse a new line, compute the size of that line in bytes and use it as an indicator.

```
import os
fileName = r"c:\\somefile.log"
fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileName)

progress = 0
with open(fileName, 'r') as inputFile:
    for line in inputFile:
        progress = progress + len(line)
        progressPercent = (1.0*progress)/fileSize

#in the end, progress == fileSize
```

Comment: Will this work with the size estimate? Like Unicode etc?

Comment: It does work. The `len` actually counts the number of bytes in the unicode string (not the number of characters). What is does actually is calling the `__len__` method in the class and returning that value.

Comment: Hmm, but that only works because I didn't specify the encoding? Reading utf8 files with this gives incorrect `line`. If I have a UTF8 file and I specify the encoding, I get character counts again.