# How to print a progress bar in terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, progress-bar

When homebrew downloads software there's this progress bar which is really nice,

```
######################################################################## 100.0%
```

I wrote some Python scripts and I run them in the terminal too, and I want to have the same progress bar as the script runs. For example if I have a long `for` loop I would like to have this progress bar as it runs through the loops. How can I print this progress bar in Python?

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this

```
import sys
import time

for n in xrange(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("#")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

You need to just write out a single "#" and then flush the tty, aka asking the console to pull from `stdout` and update.

Comment: this is a dublicate.. Note that i am writing it myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate. But this doesn't really do what the OP wants!