# How to output to the same line overwriting the previous line?

Tags: python

How to print the output on the same line by overwriting the previously printed Timing(countdown) value?

As shown below, after each second, the timing value is printed on the next row.

```
13:35:01

13:35:00

13:34:59

13:34:58

13:34:57

13:34:56
```

I want the timing value to be printed on the same row clearing the previous one.

Answer (score 65):

You can [use the "return"-character `\r` to return to the beginning of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173338/1639625). In Python 2.x, you'll have to use `sys.stdout.write` and `sys.stdout.flush` instead of `print`.

```
import time, sys
while True:
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + time.ctime())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

In Python 3.3, you can use the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) function, with `end` and `flush` parameters:

```
    print(time.ctime(), end="\r", flush=True)
```

Note, however, that this way you can only replace the last line on the screen. If you want to have a "live" clock in a more complex console-only UI, you should check out [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html).

```
import time, curses
scr = curses.initscr()
scr.addstr(0, 0, "Current Time:")
scr.addstr(2, 0, "Hello World!")
while True:
    scr.addstr(0, 20, time.ctime())
    scr.refresh()
    time.sleep(1)
curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Nice! However, after executing this, the line does not skip even if I hit enter in the terminal.

Comment: curses.endwin() sovled the problem.

Answer (score 10):

This will work like a champ:

```
print("This text is about to vanish - from first line", end='')
print("\rSame line output by Thirumalai")
```

output:

> > Same line output by Thirumalai from first line

Comment: Not in Python 3.8 with windows 10 IDLE!

Comment: I got the same result in PowerShell when running the script using `python test.py` for example, but no so in ipython or python REPL.

Answer (score 2):

I am using python 2.7

```
python --version
Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)
```

and I am using this the following function as a hook to display the download progress, by using urllib.urlretrieve

```
def hook(bcount , bsize, tsize ):
    str = "[ %3d%% of %10d] \r" % (bcount * bsize * 100/tsize , tsize)    
    print str,

urllib.urlretrieve (url, file_name, hook)
```

Explanation: the \r put the cursor at start of the line , and the comma avoid to print in a new line , if you have the same number of character for each print , this will do the trick

if you are curious about urllib and the hook I am using you'll find the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Answer (score 0):

in Python 3.* use:

var = [some data u want to work with]

```
for i in range(len(var)):
   # some work stuff
   print("\r"+str((i/len(var))*100)+"%", end="\r", flush=True)
print("\n")
```

without the "\r" at the beginning Python will just write from the start of the line, but doesn't override the previous text. Notice! it will not clear the prev. line only override it!

u can also use  print("\r"+str(**int(**(i/len(var))*100**)**)+"%", end="\r", flush=True)

the last print statement is for starting a new line after the loop than u have only integer %-values

Comment: What is the point of dividing `i` by 100 and multiplying it back by 100? The flush kwarg accepts a boolean. `flush=True` Please [edit] your answer @Uik

Comment: ah thats right da boolean! i will rewrite the example even better

Answer (score -2):

## Works in python3

But only for windows

```
import os
import time
while True:
    print(time.ctime())
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls')
```