# Delete last character printed in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to delete the last character I've printed from the previous line in python, e.g if I do print ("hello world")
I will get hello world outputted, but I'm wondering after it's been outputted would there be a way to remove the d at the end of the output so it would now only say hello worl... in short is there  a way to remove the end character of an already printed line?

Thanks

Comment: Related reading: [Replace console output in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6169217/953482), [Output to the same line overwriting previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26584003/953482)

Comment: `print("\b ",end="")` (move the cursor back then print a space) should work *sometimes*, but don't count on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to perform operations on data that has been output since it is not stored in memory as a variable.  You can however overwrite the location on the screen (if you are dealing with something like a terminal) that it is printed on to 'remove' the old data.

Here is a function you can add and call in your code to send text to a specific location on the terminal display:

```
import sys

def PrintLocate(row, column, text):
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (row, column, text))
    sys.stdout.flush()

# Elsewhere
PrintLocate(13, 37, "Hello World")
PrintLocate(13, 37 + len("Hello Worl"), " ")
```

Comment: The first part is obvious; it's the second part that OP wants. So, how to do it?

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Well... I don't _know_, but isn't it _pretty_ obvious that OP does not want to overwrite a character that was "printed" to paper, but instead wants to overwrite what was last printed with the `print` function to the terminal?

Comment: Maybe not paper, but possibly the Output tab in Visual Studio for example...
I just used paper to explain a concept.