# Python 3 Print Overwrite Same Line Before An If Statement

Tags: python-3.x

i wan to print the variable "ln" in the same line (overwriting the old output) but it doesn't seem to work before an if statement
i tried this solution [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584003/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous/26584483) but it didn't workout

i have the following code :

```
if smtn == "othr":

  #lines variable reads a file line by line
  for ln in lines:

    #i tried this solution
    print("Line Is : " + ln , end="\r", flush=True)

    if var0 == "valu0":
      #do something
    elif var1 == "valu1":
      #do something
    elif var2 == "valu2":
      #do something
```

Comment: This doesn't work in every console. Some, you can use the backspace key to erase old output, some don't support that. Some support using a return like you have here, some don't. Try it in a different console.

Comment: @Carcigenicate , i managed to get it working but now small words don't overwrite the big ones properly you still can see the end of the big word added to the small word
example :
word1 : comment
,word2 : test 
,output : testent