# Adding progress feedback in Grequests task

Tags: python, concurrency, gevent, grequests

I've followed the grequests [usage example](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests), but I'm trying to add some progress feedback. A percentage of the completed requests. How could I achieve that?

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://python-tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

def feedback(r, **kwargs):
            print "%s fetched." % r.url
            return r

rs = (grequests.get(u, callback=feedback) for u in urls)
res = grequests.map(rs)
```

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console for how to make the feedback, but the real problem is that the call to .map blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import gevent
import sys
import requests

rs = [gevent.spawn(requests.get, u) for u in urls]
[i.start() for i in rs]
while 1:
    gevent.sleep()
    percent = 0.0
    for i in rs:
        if i.successful():
            percent += 100 / len(rs)
    sys.stdout.write(('='*int(percent))+(''*(100-int(percent)))+("\r [ %d"%percent+"% ] "))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if percent == 100:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure grequests but you can do similar things with another module called [pySmartDL](https://pypi.org/project/pySmartDL/).also this module gives a download bar by default.
for more info check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633174/16915996)