# How to display a countdown on a single line in the console?

Tags: python, windows, printing, range, countdown

I need a countdown timer in python but without skipping line.

```
from time import sleep

for c in range (4,0,-1):
   print(c)
   sleep(1)
```

this code makes the countdown by jumping the lines
ex:

```
print('3')
print('2')
print('1')
```

I need that in the same line show first 3, then 2, last 1.
ex:

```
print('3,' + sleep(1) + '2,' + sleep(1) + '1.')
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "skipping line". Can you please clarify what your code is currently doing wrong?

Comment: You mean like `print(c, end=', ')`?

Comment: See if the question [**Text Progress Bar in the Console**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console) helps.

Comment: edited now, sorry.

Comment: You can print each digit with `print(c, end='\r')`. After the loop, do one `print()` to finish and go to the next line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want delete previous number in console,
you can do like

```
from time import sleep
import os

for i in range(4, 0, -1):
    os.system("cls")
    print(i)
    sleep(1)
```

this.

or you can use end parameter in print function.

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(4, 0, -1):
    print(i, end = '\r')
    sleep(1)
```

like this.

Comment: For this to work you *may* need to disable input buffering in python...

Comment: If you change the range to span numbers of more than two digits, when you get to 9 you see '90' instead of '9' in the terminal. Setting flush=True on print() doesn't remedy this issue either. Why is this?

Comment: `sh: 1: cls: not found`

Comment: @alper cls is clear command for Windows. you should use clear or method below.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(4, 0, -1):
    print(i, end = ' \r')
    sleep(1)
```

Note the space before '\r'.

When counting down from 10 to 9, 90 is displayed instead of 9 or from 100 to 99, 990 is displayed instead of 99 when no space is added before '\r'.

Adding space before '\r' prevents the extra digit from being displayed.