# Python text game health bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

I'm making a text adventure I'm using

```
def do_health
    print health,"/ 200"
```

to display health but I want to convert it to a percentage and print something like

```
|----------          |
         50%
```

depending on what percentage of health the player has left but I can't find anything elsewhere on making a health bar for idle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be able to use some of the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that needs to be done is a few simple conversion to convert your current health into a number of dashes and define the max number of dashes (*20 in this case*: `healthDashes`) to be equivalent to your max health (200: `maxHealth`).

Consider you have `80` health left. So for example if we take `healthDashes(20)/maxHealth(200)` you get `10`, this is the value that we divide our health by to convert it into the number of dashes that we want. You can then take your current `health` being `80` and the number of dashes is: `80/10 => 8 dashes`. The percentage is straight forward: `(health(80)/maxHealth(200))*100 = > 40 percent`.

Now in python you just apply that lodic above and you will get:

```
health = 80.0      # Current Health (float so division doesn't make an int)
maxHealth = 200    # Max Health
healthDashes = 20  # Max Displayed dashes

def do_health():
  dashConvert = int(maxHealth/healthDashes)            # Get the number to divide by to convert health to dashes (being 10)
  currentDashes = int(health/dashConvert)              # Convert health to dash count: 80/10 => 8 dashes
  remainingHealth = healthDashes - currentDashes       # Get the health remaining to fill as space => 12 spaces

  healthDisplay = '-' * currentDashes                  # Convert 8 to 8 dashes as a string:   "--------"
  remainingDisplay = ' ' * remainingHealth             # Convert 12 to 12 spaces as a string: "            "
  percent = str(int((health/maxHealth)*100)) + "%"     # Get the percent as a whole number:   40%

  print("|" + healthDisplay + remainingDisplay + "|")  # Print out textbased healthbar
  print("         " + percent)                         # Print the percent
```

If you call the method you get the result:

```
do_health()
>
|--------            |
         40%
```

Here are a few more examples with changing the value of `health`:

```
|----------          |  # health = 100
         50%
|--------------------|  # health = 200
         100%
|                    |  # health = 0
         0%
|------              |  # health = 68
         34%
```

Comment: Instead of using `''.join(['-' for i in range(currentDashes)])`, it would be cleaner to do `'-'*currentDashes`.

Comment: @JosephCamacho Good point, this was a few years back so it was probably a bit more rusty back then :P. I've also changed the `health` so it's a float due to how Python 2 handles integer division since I noticed OP tagged it in the question. Now it should have the correct answer in 2 and 3.