# How to get progress bar to stay on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time
import sys
progressbar = []

dashes = 1
spaces = 10
for i in range(11):
    print("Logging In[", end = "")
    for x in range(dashes):
        dash = "|"
        progressbar.append(dash)
        print(progressbar[x], end = "")
    for y in range(spaces):
        print(end = " ")

    dashes += 1
    spaces -= 1
    print("]")

sys.stdout.write()
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I was wondering how to get this progress bar to print on only one line like a game or loading screen. It prints over and over again on a new line each time and I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: `print("]")` prints a newline. You need to print a `\r` carriage return instead to go back to the start of the same line.

Comment: Please correct the indent after `for y ...`.

Comment: It will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/34325723/7340533

Answer (score -1):

You can go back at the beginning of the line by terminating your line with a "\r" (`print("something", end="\r")`) instead of the usual "\r\n" on Windows and "\n" on UNIX.

For example:

```
import time
import sys


dashes = 1
spaces = 10
for i in range(11):
    progressbar = ['|' for x in range(dashes)]
    print("Logging In [", "|" * dashes, " " * spaces, "]", end="\r")
    dashes += 1
    spaces -= 1
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Edit: The link posted by Yakir Tsuberi is more complete, don't mind my answer