# Clear last two (and more) printed lines in Linux terminal emulator

Tags: linux, terminal, console-application

I once saw a console app that visualized a progress of multiple downloads with multiple progressbars, each on its own line. I was curious how to do that, but I found only partial solutions. Here they are:

### One progressbar is easy

It is easy to clear one line with ["carriage return"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) and thus visualize one progress bar, as it is discussed [e.g. in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console). Easy to use, also a lot of helper libraries exist.

### "use ncurses"

Everybody says "use ncurses". But as far as I know every ncurses program must start with `initscr()` call, that really clears the whole screen. Your prompt is gone, your terminal history is gone. This is not what I want.

### Use terminfo from ncurses

Use `sc`, `ed` and `rc` capabilities from `terminfo`, as ilustrates this Bash script (the script is taken from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/can-i-overwrite-multiple-lines-of-stdout-at-the-command-line-without-losing-term)):

```
tput sc; while [ true ]; do tput ed; echo -e "$SECONDS\n$SECONDS\n$SECONDS"; sleep 1; tput rc; done
```

This works, but only in `xterm`. My `urxvt` term ignores it, same as e.g. `terminator`.

So what are other options?

Comment: Escape sequences perhaps http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html ?

Comment: urxvt implements the terminfo features mentioned (perhaps you're setting `TERM` to something unrelated to that terminal).

Comment: @Marged Yes, thank you, that works. I posted my own answer with a code I tested, because your comment cannot be accepted as answer. If you post your own I will be happy to accept it!

Comment: @ThomasDickey My TERM is "rxvt-unicode-256color", but even when I set it on "xterm" it does not work. Here is also said that it works only in Xterm: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

Comment: Happy I sent you in the right direction. Let's take stick to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user @Marged rightly pointed out, [ANSI escape sequences](http://[1]%20http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html) are the answer.

Here is the C code that works for me. Crucial is the line 19 which prints ANSI sequence that erases last two lines (number of lines is arbitrary, it is stated in the sequence):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void progressBar(int done, int total) {
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for (i=0; i<total; ++i) {
        printf((done < i) ? " " : "=");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        progressBar(i, 4);
        progressBar(2*i, 8);
        if (i != 4) {
            printf("\033[2A");  // This erases last two lines!
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```