# Progression bar in output depending on progression of calculation in Python

Tags: python, progress-bar

If we assume that the following code is a huge and complicated code and lasts for minutes or hours and we want to inform the user how many percents of the code are passing, what should I do?

```
num=1

for i in range(1,100000):
    num=num*i
print(num)
```

I want to inform users with progression bar, similar to installing something.
I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console/27871113) but I did not understand how to write a progression bar depending on my code progression.

In the examples similar to the mentioned link, they are defining the sleep or delaying time. this is not acceptable. Because we do not know the calculation time of Python in different code with different functions.

Comment: We won't write code for you or give suggestions unless you show what you gave tried so far.

Comment: The question that you link has good solutions to your problem. For example, if you take the function from the accepted answer you would just need to add `printProgressBar(i, 100000)` to your loop. What is it that you cannot work out about them?

Comment: @FHTMitchell why did you give me negative vote?

Comment: @David probably because _We won't write code for you or give suggestions unless you show what you tried so far._ check [ask], in particular how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @jdehesa The problem is, they are defining delaying time, while we don't know the amount of calculation time of Python in each step.

Comment: @David I'm not sure I follow. The examples use `sleep` just as a placeholder for actual computation work, you are supposed to replace that with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If your index `i` corresponds to your actuall progress, the [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) package is a good option. A simple example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(1000)):
    time.sleep(0.01)  # sleep 0.01s
```

Output:

```
1%|          | 1010/100000 [00:10<16:46, 98.30it/s]
```

Edit: The progress bar also works if the progress is not known.

```
def loop_without_known_length():
    # same as above, but the length is not known outside of this function.
    for i in range(1000):
        yield i

for i in tqdm(loop_without_known_length()):
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Output:

```
60it [00:00, 97.23it/s]
```

Comment: in this code your are defining the delaying time `0.01` but we do not know how many seconds it lasts to get the answer. even if you write it for my sample simple code it you do not know how much time it is needed to calculate each steps.

Comment: another problem is, this code doea not show a filling bar, it print percents under each other

Comment: @David I added a code snippet which does not display the time.

Comment: @David If you print something while the progress bar is running, it will continue in a new line. Otherwise it should in principle show the progress in the same line.

Comment: `0%|          | 0/1000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  1%|          | 7/1000 [00:00<00:15, 64.00it/s]
  1%|1         | 13/1000 [00:00<00:16, 59.43it/s]
  2%|1         | 17/1000 [00:00<00:18, 51.81it/s]
  2%|2         | 21/1000 [00:00<00:21, 46.34it/s]
  2%|2         | 25/1000 [00:00<00:23, 41.03it/s]
  3%|2         | 29/1000 [00:00<00:25, 38.67it/s]
  3%|3         | 32/1000 [00:00<00:26, 36.57it/s]
  4%|3         | 36/1000 [00:00<00:26, 36.57it/s]


`

Comment: I believe this is a separate issue, and you need to provide more details on where you are printing the output. (Terminal, interactive console, jupyter, etc...) Best open a new question.