# How do you use python to clear/edit lines printed in the shell?

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to use a command in python to clear/edit lines printed in the shell? if not, what is a good way to do a loading bar?

Comment: You mean something like tqdm?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `print` statement to not do a carriage return and newline, but just a carriage return:

```
print('whatever you want to print', end='\r')
```

If you want to implement a progress bar, you could do it yourself, or take a look at the many options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)