# How to create a progress bar in command line for pool processes?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have several scripts which I run using Multiprocessing pool I am trying to do a progress bar based on the scripts completed.

I checked [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console#_=_)

but I cannot figure out how I can combine the scripts completed in the counter

```
import os                                                                       
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run_process(process):                                                             
    os.system('python {}'.format(process))

processes = ('script1.py', 'script2.py','script3.py','script4.py')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(run_process, processes)
```

Comment: "combine the scripts completed in the counter" is too vague. What exactly should the counter represent?

Comment: The counter counts the completed scripts so far

Comment: Why run other Python programs through `os.system`, rather than by using the standard mechanisms for this, like the ability to import modules?

Comment: @MiaoulisNikos _The counter counts the completed scripts so far_ I’m not sure I understand what the issue is, then.

Comment: `pool.map()` blocks until all the processes have finished, so there's no indication of when individual ones have completed — so you can't have a progressbar showing how many have completed so far.

Comment: @martineau So is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide me a complete solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly differrent approach which uses [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) instead of a `multiprocessing.Pool` which make it simpler and more efficient than what's in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60583624/355230).

**Note** it uses the same `print_progress_bar.py` module that's in my other answer.

```
import concurrent.futures
import os
import subprocess
import sys

from print_progress_bar import print_progress_bar
progress_bar_kwargs = dict(prefix='Progress:', suffix='Complete', length=40)

# To simplify testing just using one script multiple times.
processes = ('./mp_scripts/script1.py', './mp_scripts/script1.py',
             './mp_scripts/script1.py', './mp_scripts/script1.py')
process_count = 0


def run_process(process):
    global process_count

    subprocess.run([sys.executable,  process])
    # Update process count and progress bar when it's done.
    process_count += 1
    print_progress_bar(process_count, len(processes), **progress_bar_kwargs)


print_progress_bar(0, len(processes), **progress_bar_kwargs) # Print 0% progress.
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:

    future_to_process = {executor.submit(run_process, process): process
                            for process in processes}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_process):
        process = future_to_process[future]
        try:
            _ = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print()
            print(f'{process} generated an exception: {exc}')

    print('Done')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [`pool.apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) because it supports a callback function that can be used to know when the target function has returned.

I used @Greenstick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34325723/355230) to display the progress bar, but I modified it mostly to conform to PEP-8 coding guidelines and placed it in a separate module named `print_progress_bar` — see below.

**Performance note:** While one *can* use `multiprocessing.Pool` to do this — I strongly suspect the code in your question is a verbatim copy of what's in the article [How to run parallel processes](https://medium.com/@leportella/how-to-run-parallel-processes-8939dafae81e) — doing so is extremely inefficient because each process will initialize its own Python interpreter **double** the number of times really necessary. First to execute the `run_process()` function itself, and then again to run the script process.

Spawning processes involves a fair amount of overhead. That overhead can be mitigated by instead running `run_process()` as a separate thread in the *current* process, which is a lighter-weight.

Switching to a `ThreadPool` is very easy, just change the line:
    `from multiprocessing import Pool`
to
    `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool`

Alternatively you can use a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` as shown in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584125/355230).

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess
import sys

from print_progress_bar import print_progress_bar
progress_bar_kwargs = dict(prefix='Progress:', suffix='Complete', length=40)

def run_process(process):
     os.system('{} {}'.format(sys.executable,  process))

def callback(_):
    """Update process count and progress bar."""
    global process_count
    process_count += 1
    print_progress_bar(process_count, len(processes), **progress_bar_kwargs)


# To simplify testing just using one script multiple times.
processes = ('./mp_scripts/script1.py', './mp_scripts/script1.py',
             './mp_scripts/script1.py', './mp_scripts/script1.py')
process_count = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print_progress_bar(0, len(processes), **progress_bar_kwargs) # Print 0% progress.

    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        results = []
        for process in processes:
            r = pool.apply_async(run_process, (process,), {}, callback)
            results.append(r)

        while results:  # Processes still running?
            results = [r for r in results if not r.ready()]

    print('Done')
```

---

`print_progress_bar.py`:

```
# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34325723/355230
def print_progress_bar(iteration, total, prefix='', suffix='', decimals=1, length=100,
                       fill='█', print_end="\r"):
    """ Print iterations progress.

        Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
        @params:
            iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
            total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
            prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
            suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
            decimals    - Optional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
            length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
            fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
            print_end   - Optional  : end character (e.g. "\r", "\r\n") (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end=print_end, flush=True)

    if iteration == total:  # Print newline on completion.
        print(flush=True)
```