# How to add progress bar during data loading?

Tags: python, oop, progress-bar

i wanted to add a progress bar to my Python code, which will update during the constructor call.
I have a base class and a derived class. All these classes are reading data from pickle files, and progress bar should be displayed as the following:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        # Loading starts here
        self.some_data = ...

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.some_more_data = ... 
        # Loading ends here
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question will probably help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console

Comment: Unfortunately not. The problem is that the amount of iterations running is varying and i do not know how much time it will take