# how to show progress in a python script?

Tags: python

I need a simple output to show progress in my python script

e.g. I have this script

```
def delete_id(list):
 r = del(id)
 print(r.json())

list = get_list()
 delete_id(list)
```

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-terminal-with-block-characters

Comment: In particular, `tqdm` from jfs's answer is super easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your script. You don't want to use `list` or `id` as variable names because they are built in functions. But you can use [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) and do something like this:

```
import enlighten

items = get_list()
pbar = enlighten.Counter(total=len(items))

for id_ in pbar(items):
    delete_id(id_)
```

If you want to do something more complicated, like have multiple progress bars, you'll want to create a manager first.

```
manager = enlighten.get_manager()
pbar = manager.counter()
```

Lot of customization and examples in the [docs](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).