# Chinese in views.py cause failure

Tags: django, decode

The Chinese words in my views.py causes a failure, when I remove those words it will be correct. These Chinese words only present in the `print` sentence.

Is this a decode/encode problem? and how can I fix it?

When I `vim` the `views.py` in my server, it show the Chinese words incorrect. So I wonder maybe it is a decode/ecnode problem, am I right?

Comment: Please update the question with your `views.py` with the Chinese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem, which happened when I use such as `("%sxxx" % var)` grammer, then I change it to, `("%s%s" % (var, u'xxx'))`

It works, hope it can help others

Answer (score 2):

Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first line of your `views.py` and mark your chinese strings as unicode by adding `u` prefix.

Also see:

- [Why declare unicode by string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170211/why-declare-unicode-by-string-in-python)

Comment: Those are not alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

use such as : ("%s%s" % (var, u'xxx'))