# Why does this sentence work after I comment it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comments

What I exactly want to know is that Whether the Sentence Work after I Comment It.

It's the script,and I'm sure that before run it I saved it.Because my Python doesn't support the word `我`, I comment it.

[image: code]

But it doesn't work.Why?Why does this sentence work after I comment it?How does the comment work?

[image: error]

Comment: Try add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the first line.

Comment: I'm running python 3 and it has no issues with the character with it in a string or comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why declare unicode by string in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170211/why-declare-unicode-by-string-in-python)

Comment: you are running Python 2 because `print` works without `()`

Comment: Also, check [PEP 0623](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) as *the error suggest*.

Comment: What I exactly want to know is that Whether the Sentence Work after I Comment It.

Comment: you are running Python 2 so you can't use native chars even in comments if you don't have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (or something similar)