# hi § symbol unrecognized

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, symbols

good morning.
I'm trying to do this and not leave me .

Can you help me?

thank you very much

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
           titulo=soup.find('h3').get_text()
      titulo=titulo.replace('§','')

 titulo=titulo.replace('§','')
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0:       ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What's the text of `h3`?

Answer (score 3):

[Define the `coding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170211/why-declare-unicode-by-string-in-python) and operate with *unicode strings*:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_page = u"<h3>§ title here</h3>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")

titulo = soup.find('h3').get_text()
titulo = titulo.replace(u'§', '')
print(titulo)
```

Prints `title here`.

Comment: tkns i only need "u" Tks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain you clearly what's the problem:

By default Python does not recognize particular characters like "à" or "ò". To make Python recognize those characters you have to put at the top of your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This codes makes Python recognize particular characters that by default are not recognized.
Another method to use the coding is using "sys" library:

```
# sys.setdefaultencoding() does not exist, here!
import sys
reload(sys)  #This reloads the sys module
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8') #Here you choose the encoding
```